# Convert MS Access SQL to Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I got it to this far:

```
MERGE INTO AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
USING (SELECT PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY, AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.rowid AS r 
    FROM AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
    INNER JOIN HISTORY_PRODUCTION
      ON (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
        AND (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM)
        AND (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.LOC_ID)
    INNER JOIN PERIOD_TO_PROCESS  
      ON (HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
        AND (HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM))
ON (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.rowid = r) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET CASES_PRODUCED = PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY;
```

but no I get this error:
 ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Original Question:

last problematic query I think...  converting ms-access sql to oracle

```
UPDATE PERIOD_TO_PROCESS INNER JOIN (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY INNER JOIN HISTORY_PRODUCTION ON
 (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM) AND 
 (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM) AND 
 (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.LOC_ID)) ON 
 (PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM) AND 
 (PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM) SET 
 AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.CASES_PRODUCED = PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY;
```

Is this one correctly done in access? don't know but it runs with out error in access  and cant figure how

applicable tables columns:

```
1. HISTORY_PRODUCTION
  - LOC_ID
  - FSCL_YR_NUM
  - FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
  - SKU_COUNT
  - PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY

2. AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
  - LOC_ID
  - COUNTOFINVEN_ID
  - FSCL_YR_NUM
  - FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
  - STOCKING_LEVEL
  - TOTAL_PALLETS_RQD
  - BAY_CASES
  - BAY_FULL_PALLETS
  - BAY_ADJUSTED_USPD
  - BAY_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT
  - BAY_PICK_PALLETS_RQD
  - BAY_PICK_FLOOR_POSITIONS
  - BULK_CASES
  - BULK_FULL_PALLETS
  - BULK_ADJUSTED_USPD
  - BULK_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT
  - BULK_PICK_PALLETS_RQD
  - BULK_PICK_FLOOR_POSITIONS
  - COMBINED_CASES
  - COMBINED_FULL_PALLETS
  - COMBINED_ADJUSTED_USPD
  - COMBINED_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT
  - COMBINED_PICK_PALLETS_RQD
  - COMBINED_PICK_FLOOR_POSITIONS
  - COMBINED_PALLET_RESERVE_RQD
  - SEPARATE_PALLET_RESERVE_RQD
  - SEPARATE_AISLES_REQUIRED
  - SEPARATE_BAYS_PER_AISLE
  - SEPARATE_PICK_SQFT
  - SEPARATE_RESERVE_SQFT
  - SEPARATE_CASEFLOW_SQFT
  - COMBINED_AISLES_REQUIRED
  - COMBINED_BAYS_PER_AISLE
  - COMBINED_PICK_SQFT
  - COMBINED_RESERVE_SQFT
  - COMBINED_CASEFLOW_SQFT
  - WEEKLY_LAYER_CASE_COUNT
  - DOCK_SQFT_COMBINED
  - DOCK_SQFT_SEPARATE
  - COMBINED_WHSE_DEPTH
  - COMBINED_WHSE_WIDTH
  - SEPARATE_WHSE_DEPTH
  - SEPARATE_WHSE_WIDTH
  - COMBINED_WHSE_SQFT
  - SEPARATE_WHSE_SQFT
  - RETURNS_SQFT
  - OVERTIME_HOURS
  - BREAK_QTY
  - SHRINK_QTY
  - OUT_OF_STOCK_QTY
  - CASES_SHIPPED
  - CASES_RCVD
  - CASES_PRODUCED
  - BREAK_COST
  - SHRINK_COST

3. PERIOD_TO_PROCESS
  - FSCL_YR_NUM
  - FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
```

Comment: when converting to Oracle you need to set the target table as `AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY` because this is what is eventually being updated

Comment: I updated the question to show my status.

Comment: Try `USING (SELECT DISTINCT PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY, AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.rowid AS r .... `

Comment: Thanks man.  I forgot all about the distinct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an update statement? Something approaching:

```
UPDATE
(
    SELECT 
        HISTORY_PRODUCTION.PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY
        ,AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.CASES_PRODUCED
    FROM 
        AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY
            INNER JOIN 
        HISTORY_PRODUCTION
            ON AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM
                AND AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM
                AND AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.LOC_ID
            INNER JOIN 
        PERIOD_TO_PROCESS  
            ON (HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM)
                AND (HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM)
)
SET AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.CASES_PRODUCED = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY;
```